# Merge multiple twilio video group rooms into one.

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I want to merge multiple twilio video group rooms into one as if they were a single video group. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this manually perhaps!

1. You have the video call Room sid's and Participant id's
2. From the existing Rooms, you can retain one or create a new Room Perhaps
3. Then move all the participant from other rooms to the desired room
4. Mark the old Room's as complete
5. And that's it, all the participant will be on the same Room